# How to guarantee rasterization of triangles in a voxel representation

Tags: opengl, algorithm, rasterizer, voxelization

There are 2 problems i am trying to solve involving rasterization of geometry in 3D.

The first is, my 3D texture is created with a top down viewd, so triangles that are perfectly orthogonal to the planes represented by the texture are not visible.

The second is, due to how rasterization in OpenGL works, if a triangle is visible inside of a voxel, but too small to cover the middle of  it, it will be discarded.

In general I am looking for a method that guarantees that if a voxel contains a triangle or part of a triangle ti will be marked as occupied.

Comment: If that's what you want, rasterization is *not* going to get you there. Or at least, not rasterization as most GPUs implement it.

Comment: I suspect you can modify the geometry based on the resolution of the current grid to achieve proper rasterization i.e be waare the saterizer works in 2D and modufy the geometry acoordingly.